# Layout Help with Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, design

I'm using the Magento 1.9 Modern Theme and trying to add the third column but having trouble.

http://www.janetscloset.com/admin4190/Library

That's the link above, I can't get it to the right. Any ideas?

Also, on my left hand column I'm trying to move the compare products and cart to the right column. How would I do that? I just want my vertical menu in the left column.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: it is cms page? or category page?